# r function or loop to create new columns and calculate values based upon limits

Tags: r, function, loops, transform

I currently use 40 lines of code to create and calculate new columns if certain conditions are met. I am trying to come up w/ a way to turn all of this code into either a loop or function to simplify my script.

Here is some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(sc1 = sample(LETTERS[1:6],15,replace=T),
                  sc1_n = sample (1:100,15),
                  sc2 = sample(LETTERS[1:6],15,replace=T),
                  sc2_n = sample (1:100,15),
                  sc3 = sample(LETTERS[1:6],15,replace=T),
                  sc3_n = sample (1:100,15),
                  ec1 = sample(LETTERS[1:6],15,replace=T),
                  ec1_n = sample (1:100,15),
                  ec2 = sample(LETTERS[1:6],15,replace=T),
                  ec2_n = sample (1:100,15),
                  ec3 = sample(LETTERS[1:6],15,replace=T),
                  ec3_n = sample (1:100,15),
                  area = sample (1:100,15))
```

I iterate through each unique value of sc1 (A-F, n=6), sc2 (A-F, n=6), and sc3 (A-F, n=6) to calculate a value, then add the unique values together to create another column, called A, B, C, D, E, or F, with 's' appended after to indicate it was a value for s, and not e, which I also iterate through after I finish with sc1, sc2, and sc3.

Here are the 40 lines of code I currently use to generate the columns and values I need:

```
dat <- transform(dat,A1s = (sc1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc1 == "A")) #create new column A1s, and calculates a number if sc1=='A'
dat <- transform(dat,A2s = (sc2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc2 == "A")) #create new column A2s, and calculates a number if sc2=='A'
dat <- transform(dat,A3s = (sc3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc3 == "A")) #same as above, except A3s and where sc3='A'
dat <- transform(dat,As = A1s + A2s + A3s) #I really don't need A1s, A2s, or A3s, except to calculate this column, As
dat <- transform(dat,B1s = (sc1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc1 == "B"))
dat <- transform(dat,B2s = (sc2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc2 == "B"))
dat <- transform(dat,B3s = (sc3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc3 == "B"))
dat <- transform(dat,Bs = B1s + B2s + B3s)
dat <- transform(dat,C1s = (sc1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc1 == "C"))
dat <- transform(dat,C2s = (sc2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc2 == "C"))
dat <- transform(dat,C3s = (sc3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc3 == "C"))
dat <- transform(dat,Cs = C1s + C2s + C3s)
dat <- transform(dat,D1s = (sc1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc1 == "D"))
dat <- transform(dat,D2s = (sc2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc2 == "D"))
dat <- transform(dat,D3s = (sc3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc3 == "D"))
dat <- transform(dat,Ds = D1s + D2s + D3s)
dat <- transform(dat,E1s = (sc1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc1 == "E"))
dat <- transform(dat,E2s = (sc2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc2 == "E"))
dat <- transform(dat,E3s = (sc3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc3 == "E"))
dat <- transform(dat,Es = E1s + E2s + E3s)
dat <- transform(dat,F1s = (sc1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc1 == "F"))
dat <- transform(dat,F2s = (sc2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc2 == "F"))
dat <- transform(dat,F3s = (sc3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (sc3 == "F"))
dat <- transform(dat,Fs = F1s + F2s + F3s)

dat <- transform(dat,A1e = (ec1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec1 == "A"))
dat <- transform(dat,A2e = (ec2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec2 == "A"))
dat <- transform(dat,A3e = (ec3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec3 == "A"))
dat <- transform(dat,Ae = A1e + A2e + A3e)
dat <- transform(dat,B1e = (ec1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec1 == "B"))
dat <- transform(dat,B2e = (ec2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec2 == "B"))
dat <- transform(dat,B3e = (ec3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec3 == "B"))
dat <- transform(dat,Be = B1e + B2e + B3e)
dat <- transform(dat,C1e = (ec1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec1 == "C"))
dat <- transform(dat,C2e = (ec2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec2 == "C"))
dat <- transform(dat,C3e = (ec3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec3 == "C"))
dat <- transform(dat,Ce = C1e + C2e + C3e)
dat <- transform(dat,D1e = (ec1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec1 == "D"))
dat <- transform(dat,D2e = (ec2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec2 == "D"))
dat <- transform(dat,D3e = (ec3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec3 == "D"))
dat <- transform(dat,De = D1e + D2e + D3e)
dat <- transform(dat,E1e = (ec1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec1 == "E"))
dat <- transform(dat,E2e = (ec2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec2 == "E"))
dat <- transform(dat,E3e = (ec3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec3 == "E"))
dat <- transform(dat,Ee = E1e + E2e + E3e)
dat <- transform(dat,F1e = (ec1_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec1 == "F"))
dat <- transform(dat,F2e = (ec2_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec2 == "F"))
dat <- transform(dat,F3e = (ec3_n * 0.01) * (area) * (ec3 == "F"))
dat <- transform(dat,Fe = F1e + F2e + F3e)
```

I'm sure there must be a way to smartly and efficiently do this via creating lists and loops or at least a function, but I've been looking and haven't found a way.

-al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a transformation like this

```
for(p in c("s","e")) {
   g <- dat[, paste0(p, "c",1:3)]
   n <- dat[, paste0(p, "c",1:3,"_n")]
   for(x in LETTERS[1:5]) {
       dat[, paste0(x,p) ] <- rowSums(n * 0.01 * (g==x) * dat$area)
   }
}
```

Here we loop over the different sets for the "s" and "e" prefix, and we extract the subset of columns related to that prefix. Next we loop over all the groups and calculate the sum of the rows for that group. Here we are trying to take advantage of as much of the information stored in the column name as possible. This will not create the temporary columns you don't need (A1s, A2s, etc)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. I have an additional question. In the 'for' line, you have LETTERS, which works fine for the data I provided, however, my real data has values like 'forest_closed', 'forest_open', etc. with a class of character. Is there something easy I can switch to make it work for my real data? Otherwise, I think this loop should work great!

Comment: You can replace `LETTERS[1:5]` with any vector you like. You can do `for (x in c("forest_closted","forest_open"))`

Comment: Sorry, another question. You're looping over different sets for the 's' and 'e' prefix. What if I wanted to loop over different sets based on 'start_class' and 'end_class'?

Comment: I don't know what start_class and end_class are. Basically i'm just using `paste()` to build column names so I can index subsets of the data.frame. If you can build it, you can extract it.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how exactly c('s','e')) is working. Is it searching for any column starting w/ 's' and 'e' and adding them to the loop? If it is, can I instead search for columns named 'start' and 'end'? I've modified p to p in c('start','end')) but I get an error: Error in `[.data.frame`(dat, , paste0(p, "c", 1:3)) : 
  undefined columns selected.

Comment: Well, are the called "startc1", "startc2", "startc3"? The paste puts a "c" in there because that's what your example had. It does not look at the names of the columns present in the data. It requires you to build the correct string value yourself.

Comment: Okay, I figured out your code logic...finally. Sorry about that. I do want to add one more for loop, but must be misplacing a bracket. Here is the modified loop: 'for(p in c("sc","ec")) {
  for(j in c("1","2","3")) {
  g <- dat[, paste0(p,j)]
  n <- dat[, paste0(p,j,"_n")]}
  for(x in LETTERS[1:6]) {
    dat[, paste0(x,p) ] <- rowSums(n * 0.01 * (g==x) * dat$area)
  }
}'

Comment: Sorry, here is the modified loop formatted correctly for stackoverflow. `for(p in c("sc","ec")) {
  for(j in c("1","2","3")) {
  g <- dat[, paste0(p,j)]
  n <- dat[, paste0(p,j,"_n")]}
  for(x in LETTERS[1:6]) {
    dat[, paste0(x,p) ] <- rowSums(n * 0.01 * (g==x) * dat$area)
  }
}`

Comment: Your nesting is off and adding another loop like that will make it much less efficient. If you need to change the `1:3` to something else, replace it with `c("1","2","3")` or some vector variable containing whatever you like.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and took out the extra loop. I would still be interested how I mis-nested the loop. However, it all works thanks to your answers.